# How do you get a list of all the urls in your Web2py application?

Tags: python, url, web2py

I am trying to create an api endpoint in Web2py and need to know what URLs where generated.

I tryed http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/api/v1/employees.json and got an api json page but when I try http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/api/v1/employees/1.json I get:
no matching pattern

api.py under controllers:

````
def v1():
    response.view = 'generic.' + request.extension
    def GET(*args, **vars):
        patterns = 'auto'
        parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns, args, vars)
        if parser.status == 200:
            return dict(content=parser.response)
        else:
            raise HTTP(parser.status, parser.error)

    def POST(table_name, **vars):
        return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)

    def PUT(table_name, record_id, **vars):
        return db(db[table_name]._id == record_id).update(**vars)

    def DELELTE(table_name, record_id):
        return db(db[table_name]._id == record_id).delete()

    return dict(GET=GET, POST=POST, PUT=PUT, DELELTE=DELELTE)```
````